# Typescript: Strong-typing (and autocomplete) for a value based on a sibling object's keys

Tags: typescript, type-inference, strong-typing

Say I have an object that looks like this:

```js
const configuration: Config = {
  options: {
    'Option 1': 'some value here',
    'Option 2': 'some other value here'
  },
  defaultOption: 'Option 1'
}
```

How can I write the type `Config` such that:

- `defaultOption` can only be one of the keys in the `.options` object. ie. `'Option 1'` or `'Option 2'` in the case above.
- `.options` can have any number of key-value pairs.
- The user doesn't have to specify the `.options` keys upfront. So, the user shouldn't have to specify `const configuration: Config<'Option 1' | 'Option 2'> = ...`. It's ok to use generics, but the user shouldn't have to specify them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do that and validate, you need to infer your config object from function argument:

```js
type Configuration<
  Options
  >
  = {
    options: Options,
    defaultOption: keyof Options
  }

const config = <
  Options extends Record<string, string>,
  Config extends Configuration<Options>,
  Default extends keyof Config['options'],
  >(config: { options: Options, defaultOptions: Default }) => config

const result = config({
  options: {
    'Option 1': 'some value here',
    'Option 2': 'some other value here'
  },
  defaultOptions: 'Option 1'
}) // ok

const result2 = config({
  options: {
    'Option 1': 'some value here',
    'Option 2': 'some other value here'
  },
  defaultOptions: 'invalid property'
}) // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmBXATgQ2CxAHgCgooB5MfRAZ1KgD56BeKAb3rLioIRoC4KPWgBpOUACYQkODABtglagkEBrCCDhIhyumQC%20xYgGNawKKeToorEmSW8aUCAA9gEBBKcAlCKawShDTAWCgIaCJQwaHhDGJk8FZozm4eXrCIqJi4yoQOtHH0ACLSsgop7p5O6praiVkA2gDk3LpNALrxjAAUllmCbFCtjoL5fJFSMvKKwnyCJVPl%20gCUNgwWmehGlsFQWBA00zYbSd0cXLMC7OJNY1AAjE2CTTRwALbQAG44chjQABYQfZNLpkW6zKAAJieUBe72gcGAgKwUG%20vwBQIgTXo%20i6kzKM10zzuj2IKygAHoKUNVNszHsDtNIcc%20ugzvRhrQBjcSTC4R9UT8-lBkVjQbC7tDnq8BYjkYL0SLMdiDHjStMxlcmmE0SgJFAwFhuEDQNjyVTnFgjVggA)

Comment: Nice trick but any other options without extra function call?

Comment: Only if you know `options` up front

Comment: Thanks, @captain-yossarian. Just for my understanding, what is it about wrapping this in a function that makes it possible to pull this off, that you can't achieve with a standalone type declaration?

Comment: @RakeshPai yest, you are right. Because if you don't know possible `options`, TS has no chance to guess it

Comment: @RakeshPai, with a function, TS will infer the generics. With a standalone declaration, you will need to add them yourself, what you said you did not want to.